# Parser exits the loop

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse the file using this code. I am unable to do it. Any help will be great
I am trying to pass the file name from a text box, it is just doing fine but the parsing exists from the loop.

```
public void ParseXML(String FileName)
{

  XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FileName);
  XmlNodeType type;
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    type = reader.NodeType;
    if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
      if (reader.Name == "PIChart")
      {
        if (reader.Name == "NumberofSectors")
        {
          m_SectorValue = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
          Sectors = m_SectorValue;
        }
        if (reader.Name == "AngleofSector")
        {
          if (reader.Name == "StartAngle")
          {
            m_StartValue = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
            StartValue.Enqueue(m_StartValue);
          }
          if (reader.Name == "EndAngle")
          {
            m_EndAngle = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
            EndAngle.Enqueue(m_EndAngle);
          }
        }
        if (reader.Name == "ColorofSectorRegion")
        {
          if (reader.Name == "Region")
          {
            m_Region = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
            Region.Enqueue(m_Region);
          }
          if (reader.Name == "Color")
          {
            m_Color = reader.Value;
            color.Enqueue(m_Color);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  reader.Close();
}
```

The file I am trying to parse

```
<PIChart>
  <NumberofSectors>5</NumberofSectors>
  <AngleofSector>
    <StartAngle>0</StartAngle>
    <EndAngle>72</EndAngle>
    <StartAngle>72</StartAngle>
    <EndAngle>144</EndAngle>
  </AngleofSector>
  <ColorofSectorRegion>
    <Region>0</Region>
    <Color>Green</Color>
  </ColorofSectorRegion>
</PIChart>
```

Comment: why so hard... how about Linq2XML?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Seems like part of your question is missing.

Comment: Its difficult to see what you are trying to do here. But have you tried using XDocument to load and then parse your xml? It is LinqToXml and will make the task much easier!

Comment: Indent your XML 4 spaces when you paste it into the question.  You can do that by highlighting all of the XML, and then pressing the `{ }` button above the editor window.

Comment: Looks like you're reading XML into a typed data model given your fields and type conversions/parsing. In that case, I'd suggest you take a look into using the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); it will do most of the heavy lifting (XML traversal, parsing and type conversion) for you and you can easily separate your serialization and data model concerns.

Comment: XmlReader has it's uses, principally huge documents. If the document isn't huge, it's not the wisest approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of your problem is this:

```
            if (reader.Name == "PIChart")
            {
                if (reader.Name == "NumberofSectors")
                {
                    m_SectorValue = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                    Sectors = m_SectorValue;
                }
                if (reader.Name == "AngleofSector")
                {
                // etc.
```

Your first conditional expects `reader.Name` to be equal to "PIChart". Then you check to see if it's equal to "NumberofSectors" or "AngleOfSector", etc. That's never going to work because `reader.Name` can't hold two separate values at the same time.

Is it possible that you're looking for an *attribute* with the name "NumberOfSectors"? You'll need to look into the [GetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Xml.XmlReader.GetAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

It would help if you'd edit your question and show at least part of the XML file that you're trying to read.

### After your comment

You'd be much better off reading it as an `XmlDocument` or using the serializer. But if you really want to read this, you'll need to use [XmlReader.ReadSubTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse those individual elements. Something like:

```
if (reader.Name == "PIChart")
{
    ParsePIChart(reader.ReadSubTree());
}
```

And your `ParsePIChart` method would read that subtree and parse the sub-elements.

Comment: <PIChart>
      <NumberofSectors>5</NumberofSectors>
      <AngleofSector>
           <StartAngle>0</StartAngle>
           <EndAngle>72</EndAngle>
     </AngleofSector>
     <ColorofSectorRegion>
         <Region>0</Region>
         <Color>Green</Color>
     </ColorofSectorRegion>
</PIChart>

Comment: I am trying to parse the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Why do it the hard way? The .Net/CLR provides all the tooling you need. [Xml Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is your friend. Just mark up your data structure(s) with suitable attributes:

```
[XmlRoot("PIChart")]
public class PieChart
{
    [XmlElement("NumberofSectors")]     public int         NumberOfSectors     { get ; set ; }
    [XmlElement("AngleofSector")]       public SectorAngle AngleOfSector       { get ; set ; }
    [XmlElement("ColorofSectorRegion")] public SectorColor ColorOfSectorRegion { get ; set ; }
}
public class SectorAngle
{
    [XmlElement] public int[] StartAngle { get ; set ; }
    [XmlElement] public int[] EndAngle   { get ; set ; }
}
public class SectorColor
{
    [XmlElement] public int    Region { get ; set ; }
    [XmlElement] public string Color  { get ; set ; }
}
```

And you can deserialize your XML as easily as this:

```
string xml = @"
  <PIChart>
    <NumberofSectors>5</NumberofSectors>
    <AngleofSector>
      <StartAngle>0</StartAngle>
      <EndAngle>72</EndAngle>
      <StartAngle>72</StartAngle>
      <EndAngle>144</EndAngle>
    </AngleofSector>
    <ColorofSectorRegion>
      <Region>0</Region>
      <Color>Green</Color>
    </ColorofSectorRegion>
  </PIChart>
" ;

PieChart chart = Rehydrate<PieChart>(xml) ;

...

public static T Rehydrate<T>( string xml )
{
  T instance ;
  using ( StringReader reader = new StringReader( xml ) )
  {
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    instance = (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader) ;
  }
  return instance ;
}
```